# Having trouble calling functions for a craps game I'm writing in Perl

Tags: perl, input, subroutine

I'm writing a craps game in perl(rules provided via source code comments). One of the features in this craps game written in perl is the ability to ask the user whether they want to continue betting or whether they want to leave the game. The problem I am running into is that any time the user types in 'bet' none of the other functions seem to be getting called and the program simply terminates the same way it should terminate when the user types in 'leave'.

I have tried splitting up the program into even more functions and tracing the direction of the function calls by hand. While I would consider myself to have programing experience in other languages I'm relatively new to perl and the syntax is very different from other languages.
Expected results:

typing bet calls the other functions and depending on the dice roll those functions call other functions and when the user types in leave the program simply terminates.

Actual results:

the program terminates as soon as the user enters anything on the keyboard

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $user_money= 500;#AMOUNT OF MONEY THE USER STARTS OUT WITH
my $die=0;#WHAT NUMBER THE DIE ROLLS, IS BETWEEN 1 AND 6
my $total_dicenum=0; #TOTAL VALUE OF THE ROLL
my $betorleave="";#TAKES IN USER INPUT REGARDING WHETHER THEY WANT TO CONTINUE BETTING OR LEAVE THE GAME
my $wager=0;#HOW MUCH MONEY THE USER BETS
my $numrolls=0;#KEEPS TRACK OF THE NUMBER OF TIMES THE USER HAS ROLLED THE DICE
my $player_point=0;#THE PLAYER'S 'POINT' THAT GET'S DETERMINED AFTER THE FIRST ROLL OF DICE


#DETERMINES WHETHER THE PLAYER HAS WON OR LOST A GAME
sub result(){

if($numrolls==1){

    if($total_dicenum==7 or $total_dicenum==11){
    print"you won!\n";
    $player_point=$total_dicenum;
    $user_money = $user_money +($wager*2);
    $total_dicenum==0;

    }
elsif($total_dicenum==2 or $total_dicenum==3 or $total_dicenum==12){
    print"you lost\n";
    $player_point=$total_dicenum;
    $user_money = $user_money-$wager;
    $total_dicenum==0;

    }
else{
    bet();
        }

    }
else{#ROLLS FOLLWING THE INITAL ROLL
if($total_dicenum==$player_point){
    print"you won!\n";
    $user_money = $user_money+($wager*2);
    $total_dicenum=0;
    main();
}
elsif($total_dicenum==7){
    print"you lost\n";
    $user_money = $user_money-$wager;
    $total_dicenum=0;
    main();
}
else{
    bet();
}
}
}



#DICE ROLLER FUNCTION
sub rollDice(){

print"rolling dice...\n";
$die = 1 + int rand(6);
print"you rolled $die\n";
}
#BETTING FUNCTION
sub bet(){
print"how much money do you want to wager?\n";
print"you currently have $user_money dollars\n";
$wager=<STDIN>;
rollDice();
$total_dicenum+=$die;
print"your total score is $total_dicenum\n";
$numrolls++;
result();
}



#BELOW IS MAIN SUBROUTINE WHERE ALL THE ABOVE SUBROUTINES ARE CALLED
sub main(){
print"Welcome to craps! Here's $user_money dollars!\n";
print"would you like to place a bet or would you like to leave?(bet/leave)\n";
$betorleave=<STDIN>;

if($betorleave eq 'bet'){
    bet();

}
if($betorleave eq 'leave'){
    print"FINAL BALANCE:\n";
    print"$user_money\n";
}


}
#CALLS THE MAIN FUNCTION
main();


#WHAT THIS PROGRAM IS SUPPOSED TO DO:

#Each player will start with $500.00. Initially, and after each turn give the user the option of betting or leaving the program. 
#Implement this any way you wish, but make it clear to the user what their options are. 
#If the user chooses to place a bet, ask for the amount that will be wagered and start that “turn,” or bet.
#Each turn will consist of one or more rolls of the dice. 
#For each roll, the program should display the result of both die and the total value of the roll. 
#Then indicate the outcome from that roll (win/lose/continue rolling). 
#Once a turn, or bet is finished, indicate the outcome of the bet and the updated balance. 
#When the user chooses to exit the program display their final balance. 
#Total value of dice after first roll: 7 or 11 – player wins 2, 3, or 12 – player loses 
#Any other value and the player rolls again – the total of the dice is now their “point” 
#Total value of dice following the initial roll: The players “point” – player wins 7 – player loses 
#Any other value and the player rolls again until rolling a 7 or their point
```

Comment: This is very difficult to follow, all un-indented ... and so long.  But I notice one thing: you don't remove newline from user's input, after you've read from `<STDIN>`. So `$betorleave`, with the linefeed at its end, can't be `eq` to either of strings `bet` or `leave`.  Need `chomp $betorleave;` there.

Comment: [`perldoc -f chomp`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#chomp). There is also rarely a need to use function prototypes (the `()` in the `sub` declarations), and this is not one of those times.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you read data from STDIN using `<STDIN>`, you get the newline attached to the end of the string. You usually don't want it, so you remove it using `chomp()`.

So, where you have:

```
$betorleave=<STDIN>;
```

You need to have:

```
chomp($betorleave=<STDIN>);
```

Some more (free!) tips:

1. Please learn to indent your code.
2. Please don't use prototypes on subroutines (unless you can explain why they shouldn't be used in most cases).
3. Think about the scope of your variables. In general, global variables are bad and inside a subroutine you should only use variables that are either passed into the subroutine as parameters or declared inside the subroutine. Your `$betorleave` variable, for example, is only ever used in the `main()` subroutine, so it should be declared inside that subroutine.